Navigation menu showing active color on wrong page
I need help with my navigation menu showing the active color wrongly. When I first load the website or click on a page, the color loads accurately. However, when I click to go to another page, the active color stays on the previous page and doesn’t change to show the current page. Hover works fine. I used the Elementor Header & Footer Builder Plugin to build my website header and navigation menu. I've tried inserting various codes into my Custom CSS (Royal Addons Plugin as I don't have Elementor Pro), but nothing seems to work.
-ADDITIONAL INFO (As requested)-
I actually didn't include any additional CSS code for the colors, all I did was set up the colors when creating my header using the Elementor Header & Footer Builder plugin.
The only custom CSS I have is to shrink my menu for tablet and mobile screens, as follows:
@media(max-width:1024px){
.nav-container {
display: none;
}
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I actually didn't include any additional CSS code for the colors, all I did was set up the colors when creating my header using the Elementor Header & Footer Builder plugin.
I've updated my question, please refer above.
